# Convert column stored as text in format: yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000 to date in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a dataset where a column with the format yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000 is stored in text format, how do I convert it to date format using mySQL?

Comment: Look into using `STR_TO_DATE`.

Comment: Simply replace `'T'` with space...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `STR_TO_DATE()` as shown below:

```
select 
  str_to_date(b, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%f') as converted
from a;
```

Result:

```
b                        converted
-----------------------  --------------------------
2001-02-03T04:05:06:789  2001-02-03 04:05:06.789000
2020-05-26T18:19:20:213  2020-05-26 18:19:20.213000
```

Data script:

```
create table a (b varchar(23));                          
insert into a (b) values ('2001-02-03T04:05:06.789');
insert into a (b) values ('2020-05-26T18:19:20.213');
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tbT6udmcyBkYcZEQT8ozzY/1).